# LFS: 9.1 - 6.10 readelf missing libdebuginfod.so.1

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, linux-from-scratch, readelf

First time building LFS, I managed to get to the 6th chapter, but am stuck on the check for the second toolchain, after running

```
gcc -dumpspecs | sed -e 's@/tools@@g'             \
-e '/\*startfile_prefix_spec:/{n;s@.*@/usr/lib/ @}' \
-e '/\*cpp:/{n;s@$@ -isystem /usr/include@}' >    \
`dirname $(gcc --print-libgcc-file-name)`/specs
```

I start the compilation test, but readelf fails saying it's missing `libdebuginfod.so.1`, can't seem to find any information on that error regarding LFS.

content of `dummy.log`

```
Reading specs from /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/specs
COLLECT_GCC=cc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/tools/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/tools --with-local-prefix=/tools --with-native-system-header-dir=/tools/include --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-multilib --disable-bootstrap --disable-libgomp
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.2.0 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /tools/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/cc1 -quiet -v -isystem /usr/include dummy.c -quiet -dumpbase dummy.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase dummy -version -o /tmp/cczEXDBy.s
GNU C17 (GCC) version 9.2.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 9.2.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version none
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/tools/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include
 /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/include
 /tools/include
 /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C17 (GCC) version 9.2.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 9.2.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version none
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 7ab960f97c4082762732ed6fc672dd69
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccRYb5Iz.o /tmp/cczEXDBy.s
GNU assembler version 2.34 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.34
COMPILER_PATH=/tools/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/:/tools/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/:/tools/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/:/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/:/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/:/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/:/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /tools/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/collect2 -plugin /tools/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/tools/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccF0Eu8x.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/../lib/crt1.o /usr/lib/../lib/crti.o /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/crtbegin.o -L/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0 -L/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib /tmp/ccRYb5Iz.o --verbose -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state -lc -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/crtend.o /usr/lib/../lib/crtn.o
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.34
  Supported emulations:
   elf_x86_64
   elf32_x86_64
   elf_i386
   elf_iamcu
   elf_l1om
   elf_k1om
using internal linker script:
==================================================
/* Script for -z combreloc -z separate-code */
/* Copyright (C) 2014-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   Copying and distribution of this script, with or without modification,
   are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
   notice and this notice are preserved.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64",
              "elf64-x86-64")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)
ENTRY(_start)
SEARCH_DIR("=/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .interp         : { *(.interp) }
  .note.gnu.build-id  : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  .hash           : { *(.hash) }
  .gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
  .dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
  .dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
  .gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
  .gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
  .gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
  .rela.dyn       :
    {
      *(.rela.init)
      *(.rela.text .rela.text.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
      *(.rela.fini)
      *(.rela.rodata .rela.rodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
      *(.rela.data .rela.data.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
      *(.rela.tdata .rela.tdata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.td.*)
      *(.rela.tbss .rela.tbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.tb.*)
      *(.rela.ctors)
      *(.rela.dtors)
      *(.rela.got)
      *(.rela.bss .rela.bss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
      *(.rela.ldata .rela.ldata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.l.*)
      *(.rela.lbss .rela.lbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.lb.*)
      *(.rela.lrodata .rela.lrodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.lr.*)
      *(.rela.ifunc)
    }
  .rela.plt       :
    {
      *(.rela.plt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rela_iplt_start = .);
      *(.rela.iplt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rela_iplt_end = .);
    }
  . = ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE));
  .init           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.init)))
  }
  .plt            : { *(.plt) *(.iplt) }
.plt.got        : { *(.plt.got) }
.plt.sec        : { *(.plt.sec) }
  .text           :
  {
    *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
    *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
    *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
    *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
    *(SORT(.text.sorted.*))
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf.em.  */
    *(.gnu.warning)
  }
  .fini           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
  }
  PROVIDE (__etext = .);
  PROVIDE (_etext = .);
  PROVIDE (etext = .);
  . = ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE));
  /* Adjust the address for the rodata segment.  We want to adjust up to
     the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
  . = SEGMENT_START("rodata-segment", ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)));
  .rodata         : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*) }
  .rodata1        : { *(.rodata1) }
  .eh_frame_hdr   : { *(.eh_frame_hdr) *(.eh_frame_entry .eh_frame_entry.*) }
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RO { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .gnu_extab   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gnu_extab*) }
  /* These sections are generated by the Sun/Oracle C++ compiler.  */
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.exception_ranges*) }
  /* Adjust the address for the data segment.  We want to adjust up to
     the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE), CONSTANT (COMMONPAGESIZE));
  /* Exception handling  */
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RW { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
  .gnu_extab      : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gnu_extab) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.exception_ranges*) }
  /* Thread Local Storage sections  */
  .tdata          :
   {
     PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__tdata_start = .);
     *(.tdata .tdata.* .gnu.linkonce.td.*)
   }
  .tbss           : { *(.tbss .tbss.* .gnu.linkonce.tb.*) *(.tcommon) }
  .preinit_array    :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  }
  .init_array    :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.init_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  }
  .fini_array    :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.fini_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  }
  .ctors          :
  {
    /* gcc uses crtbegin.o to find the start of
       the constructors, so we make sure it is
       first.  Because this is a wildcard, it
       doesn't matter if the user does not
       actually link against crtbegin.o; the
       linker won't look for a file to match a
       wildcard.  The wildcard also means that it
       doesn't matter which directory crtbegin.o
       is in.  */
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.ctors))
    /* We don't want to include the .ctor section from
       the crtend.o file until after the sorted ctors.
       The .ctor section from the crtend file contains the
       end of ctors marker and it must be last */
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.ctors))
  }
  .dtors          :
  {
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.dtors))
  }
  .jcr            : { KEEP (*(.jcr)) }
  .data.rel.ro : { *(.data.rel.ro.local* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.local.*) *(.data.rel.ro .data.rel.ro.* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*) }
  .dynamic        : { *(.dynamic) }
  .got            : { *(.got) *(.igot) }
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END (SIZEOF (.got.plt) >= 24 ? 24 : 0, .);
  .got.plt        : { *(.got.plt) *(.igot.plt) }
  .data           :
  {
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
    SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
  }
  .data1          : { *(.data1) }
  _edata = .; PROVIDE (edata = .);
  . = .;
  __bss_start = .;
  .bss            :
  {
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
   /* Align here to ensure that the .bss section occupies space up to
      _end.  Align after .bss to ensure correct alignment even if the
      .bss section disappears because there are no input sections.
      FIXME: Why do we need it? When there is no .bss section, we do not
      pad the .data section.  */
   . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  .lbss   :
  {
    *(.dynlbss)
    *(.lbss .lbss.* .gnu.linkonce.lb.*)
    *(LARGE_COMMON)
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  . = SEGMENT_START("ldata-segment", .);
  .lrodata   ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)) :
  {
    *(.lrodata .lrodata.* .gnu.linkonce.lr.*)
  }
  .ldata   ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)) :
  {
    *(.ldata .ldata.* .gnu.linkonce.l.*)
    . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  _end = .; PROVIDE (end = .);
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_END (.);
  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
  .gnu.build.attributes : { *(.gnu.build.attributes .gnu.build.attributes.*) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1 */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2 */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line .debug_line.* .debug_line_end) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* DWARF 3 */
  .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
  /* DWARF Extension.  */
  .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }
  .debug_addr     0 : { *(.debug_addr) }
  .gnu.attributes 0 : { KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes)) }
  /DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) *(.gnu_debuglink) *(.gnu.lto_*) }
}


==================================================
/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: mode elf_x86_64
attempt to open /usr/lib/../lib/crt1.o succeeded
/usr/lib/../lib/crt1.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/../lib/crti.o succeeded
/usr/lib/../lib/crti.o
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/crtbegin.o succeeded
/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/crtbegin.o
attempt to open /tmp/ccRYb5Iz.o succeeded
/tmp/ccRYb5Iz.o
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc.a succeeded
/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc.a
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.so succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.so
opened script file /usr/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.so
attempt to open libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.so.1 succeeded
/usr/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.so.1
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc.a succeeded
/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc.a
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libc.so failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libc.a failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libc.so failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/../lib/libc.so succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/../lib/libc.so
/usr/lib/../lib/libc.so
opened script file /usr/lib/../lib/libc.so
attempt to open /lib/libc.so.6 succeeded
/lib/libc.so.6
attempt to open /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a succeeded
/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a
(/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
attempt to open /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 succeeded
/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a
/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc.a succeeded
/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc.a
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.so succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.so
opened script file /usr/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.so
attempt to open libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.so.1 succeeded
/usr/lib/../lib/libgcc_s.so.1
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc.a succeeded
/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/libgcc.a
attempt to open /tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/crtend.o succeeded
/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/crtend.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/../lib/crtn.o succeeded
/usr/lib/../lib/crtn.o
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by /lib/libc.so.6
found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

The one thing I did differently was on section 6.7, just after entering the chroot, gcc was missing, even though it was present on `/tools/bin`, so as per another post I did:

`ln -sv /tools/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

This got gcc to work, and I managed to complete the compilation, and yes I have tried restarting it (3 times), but the result was the same on that part.

I'm running x86_64 Manjaro Linux 5.6.12-1-MANJARO

Comment: `libdebuginfod.so` is *not* installed in LFS. It *may* come from either **1)** *libelf*, which isn't part of LFS; or **2)** *elfutils*, which is only included to obtain `libelf.so` (config instructions specifically say `--disable-debuginfod`) ...or **3)** it's on your host system and some wires got crossed during your build. It's not beyond the realm of possibilities that binutils (i.e. `readelf`) would link against it, if its `./configure` found it. My guess is, at some point in Ch. 5, an unmount of the LFS partition occurred (i.e. a reboot) and/or the $LFS variable was not (re)set.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I don't think a unset $LFS variable was the problem, I didn't reboot a single time during the last 2 attempts, and in fact $LFS is still set to this day. Regarding `libdebuginfod.so`, should I then try to remove it from the host system?

Comment: No, if it's on your host system then it needs to stay there. The fact that you had to create a symlink to get `gcc` working means your Ch. 5 tool chain is probably broken. I would start over, from the very beginning, but that's just me.

Comment: I will, thanks a lot for the insight and suggestions!